# JS wrong number parsing from string

Tags: javascript, parsing, numbers, biginteger, int64

I'm trying to parse a big int (int64) from a string...
I've set up a little test, and I'm getting the wrong number after parsing it... I only get **even** numbers, never **odd** numbers...

This is my test:

```
var test = "10202853558883111";
console.log(test); // outputs 10202853558883111

var iTest = parseInt(test);
console.log(iTest); // outputs 10202853558883112

var fTest = parseFloat(test);
console.log(fTest); // outputs 10202853558883112

var nTest = Number(test);
console.log(nTest); // outputs 10202853558883112
```

**WTF?!?!?!**
Could some one explain this, and more importantly, can you please help me solve it... /:

Comment: Javascript numbers are IEEE floats, with only 52 bits of precision.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t

Answer (score 0):

The number is too long, and exceeds Javascript's precison. Look:

```
parseInt("10202853558883111")
>  10202853558883112
parseInt("1020285355888311") // One less digit
>  1020285355888311
```

Comment: At 12.4K rep why not VTC as one of the many duplicates that exist?

Comment: You are right, I should've done that